# How put links in wordpress dynamic sidebar?

Tags: html, css, widgets, sidebar

i would like put link after each widget in dynamic sidebar. I thinks is possible if i use static sidebar, but i don't found any tutorial for this.

Thanks you

Comment: Welcome on the SO, we have SE Wordpress page for this kind of question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use[Widget Logic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/) it adds a new filter

```
widget_content
```

which you can hook your function to and add link to it somthing like:

```
add_filter('widget_content','add_link_to_widgets');
function add_link_to_widgets($content){
   return $content . '<br /><a href="http://www.domain.com">my link</a>'
}
```

### Update

You are missing the point, the plugin is great if you want to use his ability to limit the display of widgets, **Beside** that it add a new filter.

so you can use that filter like i said to add your links, each widget has an id you can add the link based on that.

Comment: Thanks but what I put in field widget logic ?

Comment: Nothing unless you want to use the logic part of the widget logic

Comment: So I put "add_filter('widget_content','add_link_to_widgets');
function add_link_to_widgets($content){
   return $content . '<br /><a href="http://www.domain.com">my link</a>'
}" in functions.php and if i want unique link for each widget ?